What is the type for a Struct with the Anchor account macro applied?
I am trying to make a token transfer function that either uses a Signer as authority (ie, when transferring from a regular accounts) or an Account as authority (eg when transferring from a PDA account).
My understanding that union types (1 | 2) are done with Enums in Rust:
enum Authority<'info, T> {
    Signer(Signer<'info>),
    Account(Account<'info, T>),
}

But that complains, quite reasonably:

the trait anchor_lang::AccountSerialize is not implemented for T

This makes sense - Account needs to take a generic for 'Struct with the Anchor account macro applied' instead of 'T'. But what type do I specify for that?

Actually from @ngundotra, because I sit near him:
enum Authority<'info, T: AccountSerialize + AccountDeserialize + Clone> {
    Signer(Signer<'info>),
    Account(Account<'info, T>),
}

